# Trying to scrape restaurant menu data using node.js / cheerio - but returning blank array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to scrape some menu information from the following restaurant: Red Cow url: "http://redcowmn.com/50th-street-menu/"
I want menu item name and the price, for now I am trouble-shooting just getting name information. Can someone help my in troubleshooting my code? Thanks.
I have tried the following code:

```html
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var fs = require("fs");

var url = "http://redcowmn.com/50th-street-menu/";

request(url, function(err, response, html) {
    if(!err) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
      var allItems = $("#block-yui_3_17_2_9_1423750151911_47600").children();
      var items = [];
      allItems.each(function(index) {
          var result = $("#block-yui_3_17_2_9_1423750151911_47600").children().eq(0).children().eq(5).find("#menu-item-title").text();
          if(result !== "") {
            items.push(result);
          }
      });

      fs.writeFile("output1.txt", JSON.stringify(items, null, 4), function(err) {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Data has been added to a file.");
        }
      })
      console.log(items);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please include the relevant error messages within your question, Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: can you console log your html data passed to cheerio and see if the data you're trying to extract is there? often times 'request' module can't get most of the data especially if it's ajax or single page apps like react or angular. just make sure first if the html you're getting is Okay.